# What are the emotional characteristics of Dracula from Bram Stoker's original novel?

Tags: dracula

I am doing a project which requires me to have the characteristics of Dracula's emotions and mental state. I hope I could get some help.

Comment: Hi there! What kind of "project"? While I _think_ this question _may_ be on-topic for the site, you still have to tell what kind of research you've already done, so that your question doesn't come off as unclear (I'll be honest, at the moment, it is a bit). May I interest you in taking the [tour] and browsing the [help] to see how you could [edit] your question to make it a better fit for the site?

Answer (score 2):

I always understood his emotions to be a bit in conflict with themselves. Dracula as a character and as a being is a representation of Stroker’s views on society. Published during the Romantic period, Stroker materializes a character that he sees as an emblem of those in power (after all it’s no coincidence Dracula was a Foreign Nobleman). What is Dracula’s main sin? Lust. For life, for sex, for power, and of course for blood. His main sin could also be argued as Greed but I feel Lust is more accurate due to the hyper sexuality of both the Romantic age and Dracula’s nature. Dracula survives by literally feeding off of others (this is a metaphor FYI). He is lonely, as there are not others like him, and therefore seeks companionship. But the only companionship he can find is by killing and transforming. So I think you have this complex character of a being who has lived for very long by preying and taking the life force of those who are weaker (a representation of the Feudal institutions of Monarchy and Nobility), but he is not a beast ignorant of the consequences of his actions. Rather he’s more like a drunk who drinks more to forget the pain of his existence. And in small moments of sobriety and loneliness you do a profound sense of gravitas and self-reflection.

I think, to distill all of this into one thought, his emotion and mental state is that of a being that knows he is evil, knows what he does is wrong, but won’t stop doing it. In a sense he is the ultimate personification of this aspect of mankind.